# Updating HIVE table with new records and upsert records based on key

Tags: mapreduce, hive

I am following below approch -

There is table WORK.DATA_PERM that is avialble and new and data that has to be updated is in such a form like if assuming that are 100 rows in WORK.DATA_PERM and new file have 10 records out of which 9 has to be updated and 1 new record-

Steps followed are -

1. Create a new table WORK.DATA_PTY and insert it with all the record of table WORK.DATA_PERM .
2. Append this table from the file which as been recieved (10 rows ) referred above.
3. Run below query to get desired data -

select T1.PTY_KEY, T1.PRCS_DT
from WORK.DATA_PTY T1 INNER JOIN
(select PTY_KEY, max(PRCS_DT) as MAX_DATE from WORK.DATA_PTY group by PTY_KEY) T2
on  T2.PTY_KEY  = T1.PTY_KEY
and T2.MAX_DATE = T1.PRCS_DT

We want to use Java Map Reduce for doing this activity ? Please suggest approch. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Map Reduce for doing this activity. After writing your mapper and reducer code in java, you can also plug them into your hive query.

You can see how to write custom mapper and reducer for hive queries [here](http://dev.bizo.com/2009/10/hive-map-reduce-in-java.html)

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17705252/2522851)